# why nestjs swargger string array not working

Tags: swagger, nestjs

```js
export class AdministratorLoginDto {
  @ApiProperty()
  userName: number[];
}
```

I set userName with number[], but i get the openapi is string[].

I set userName with number[], but i get the openapi json is string[].

```json
{
  "AdministratorLoginDto": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "userName": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "type": "string" // question: why this type is not number?
        }
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "userName"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this :

```js
export class AdministratorLoginDto {
  @ApiProperty({
     type: Number,
     isArray: true,
  })
  userName: number[];
}
```